# Putty shortcut to a path

Tags: putty

How do i create a shortcut command in Putty to go to a path? e.g. i am lazy to type in a long path to acccess into the Error folder. I want to just type in "Error" in the putty and it will link me to the folder.

I have seen someone do that. Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just alias "Error" to "cd /path/to/your/Error" in your ~/.bashrc

Something like this:

```
alias Error='cd /path/to/your/Error'
```

And after a re-login or `source ~/.bashrc` you will be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am too new. May i know where is the ~/.bashrc

Comment: After log in, in the shell window, just run `nano ~/.bashrc` ;)